# Trying to persist a largish constant collection in memory asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, configuration, scalability

Writing an MVC app that makes use of a large constant collection of "categories" 8000+.  The categories are pretty simple, id, name, parentid.  I am trying to build from the ground up with scalability in mind.  Specifically I am hoping for large amounts of traffic/io (less worried about the amount of data).  Because of that I don't want to store my categories in a database because planning for large amounts of IO gets complicated.  I don't want to have to come up with and maintain a sharding strategy for this.  It seems overkill.  What I am working towards is getting my collection stored in memory so that it can be accessed quickly.  Tried adding to project settings/ web config.  I think I have everything configured correctly.  Looks something like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Setting" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value>
          <ArrayOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <Category>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <ParentId>0</ParentId>
              <Name>Art</Name>
            </Category>
            <Category>
              <Id>2</Id>
              <ParentId>0</ParentId>
              <Name>Baby</Name>
            </Category>
            .
            .
            .
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Error   2   An expression is too long or complex to compile...
```

Assuming this means my current approach is no good...  I know a lot of people create classes for their constants to store strings and connections, but those are very small objects in comparison. I don't want to have to re-construct my collection every time a request to my site is made.

So to summarize.  How do you store a collection like this in memory for the lifetime of the MVC app?  Is it even possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into using the Asp.net Cache. It will let you provide application wide caching of your shared data

Comment: That sounds promising.  Any good links to share?  Or could you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: Here's an article that might be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.90).aspx